# python correct regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to implement hashtags. I need correct pattern. string must includes min one number or char. please do not use [a-zA-Z0-9], I do not need only english letters. use \w+ . Sorry for bad english.

```
#_ //bad
#__ //bad
#____d //good
#_1 // good
#______2 // good
#d_2____ // good
#python_regex___pattern_ // good
```

Comment: English aside, what is the input string and what is your desired output?

Comment: str = '#python #_ruby #____ #__ #csharp____ #_12 #_1 #_____p  #p___'.
# output: python, _ruby, __ #csharp____, _12, _1, _____p, p___

Comment: Edit your question with this and what is your desired output?

Comment: I do not need only underscores.

Comment: Not sure if it works in Python but something like `#(\p{L}|\d|_)+`. The `\p{L}` part is supposed to match any unicode letter

Comment: Actually, this one seems better: `#_*(\p{L}|\d)+_*(\p{L}|\d)*_*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern matches a hashtag followed by zero or more underscores followed by one or more non-underscore-non-whitespace chars followed by zero or more underscores (with the latter two repeated one or more times in a non-capturing group):

```
p = re.compile('#_*(?:[^_\s]+_*)+')

>>> bool(p.match('#d__'))
True
>>> bool(p.match('#__'))
False
>>> bool(p.match('#abc'))
True
>>> bool(p.match('#ab_c_'))
True
>>> p.findall('#_hashtag_abc_ hello #world')
['#_hashtag_abc_', '#world']
```

Comment: doesn't seem to catch '#python_regex___pattern_'

Comment: also be aware that this matches things like '#djsdjhé_èé'é'è' (not authorized in many tags systems)

Comment: @ValLeNain OP:  "I do not need only english letters"

Comment: @schwobaseggl I think he's refering to russian or chinese characters. Not punctuation marks. True that his post isn't clear on that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = ['#d__', '#__', '#abc', '#ab_c_', '#python_regex___pattern_']
data = {i:bool(re.findall('\w+', i) and re.findall('_+', i)) for i in s}
```

Output:

```
{'#abc': False, '#d__': True, '#python_regex___pattern_': True, '#__': True, '#ab_c_': True}
```

Comment: #abc is supposed to be valid

Comment: @ValLeNain actually, the OP did not specify if a hashtag could include all letters. In the OP's desired output, all hashtags had at least one "_" in them. Thus, I applied that logic to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a regex that

1. Starts with a `#`,
2. Contains at lease one `_`,
3. Contains a non ascii alphanumeric.

The problem with using `\w` here is that that set contains a `_` and Python does not support `\p{L}` to match any Unicode letter.

You can use:

```
^#(?=.*_)(?=.*[^_\s]+).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ze8aC/1/)